# Add properties to object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm trying to set some object properties, but I get this error sometimes:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined

The code:

```
var obj = {};

obj['fields'][4]['name'] = value;
```

yes, 4 does not exist, but why it is not created?

Comment: obj.fields doesn't exist yet. You'll need to set that property (with an array, presumably) before you can access the 5th item in it.

Comment: 1. which statement rises the error?
2. if obj.fileds is not defined, `obj['fields'][4]['name'] = value` rises an error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, it's telling you `obj['fields']` is undefined.  And no, it does not automatically create nesting for you.

```
var obj = {};
obj['fields'] = {};
obj['fields'][4] = {};
obj['fields'][4]['name'] = value;
```

When working with an object, if you are unsure whether or not it has it's nesting already (and you don't want to overwrite it if it does), you can do the following:

```
obj['fields'] = obj['fields'] || {}
obj['fields'][4] = obj['fields'][4] || {};
//etc
```

To check for undefined:

```
if(!obj['fields']){} // undefined returns falsey
//or 
if('fields' in obj == false){} // notice you can't lead with ! here
//or
if(obj['fields'] === undefined){} // note the triple ===
```

Comment: wow that sucks. in php they would be created :/ How can I check if the properties exist so I don't overwrite them?

Answer (score 1):

You have to init the the properties first:

```
var obj = {};

obj['fields'] = new Array();
obj['fields'][4] = new Array();
obj['fields'][4]['name'] = value;
```

Comment: If the intent is to assign string attributes to the object, I would not use an Array for the `obj['fields'][4]` object.  Depending on how you use it, it may still work - but a regular `{}` object would probably be better.

Comment: Indeed. In fact, there are many ways to achieve it. This is just the first that come to my mind :P.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to read a non-existing property doesn't create it. The exact reason that you get an error is that trying to access `fields` returns `undefined`, and you can't access any properties from an `undefined` value.

To set the value, you need to create all parents:

```
obj.fields = [];
obj.fields[4] = {};
obj.fields[4].name = value;
```